# How to change data in the ListView item that is outside of the screen?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I am working on my music player application using toolbar and ListView. In my toolbar I have buttons that allow to play next and previous audio from the ListView and change ImageButton in each ListView item. But, for example, if my current playing audio is located at the bottom of the ListView and next audio is not visible at all, when I press button "next" my application crashes because I can't change ImageButton in ListView item, that is outside of the screen. [This is how it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHQ3y.png) This is my code for the adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;
    MusicList music_list;
    LayoutInflater layout_inflater;

    MyAdapter(Context context, MusicList music_list)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.music_list = music_list;
        this.layout_inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return music_list.Size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return music_list.GetAudio(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
        {
            view = layout_inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

        view.setTag(position);
        AudioFile audio_file = GetAudioFile(position);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(audio_file.GetTitle());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist)).setText(audio_file.GetArtist());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time)).setText(audio_file.GetDurationString());

        ImageView play_pause = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
        play_pause.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);

        return view;
    }

    AudioFile GetAudioFile(int position)
    {
        return ((AudioFile) getItem(position));
    }
}
```

My crash log:

```
10-02 16:53:05.577 12344-12344/agolubeff.mymusicplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: agolubeff.mymusicplayer, PID: 12344
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=agolubeff.mymusicplayer flg=0x10 (has extras) } in agolubeff.mymusicplayer.SongList$2@398ef693
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:876)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at agolubeff.mymusicplayer.SongList.UpdateUI(SongList.java:141)
    at agolubeff.mymusicplayer.SongList.access$300(SongList.java:30)
    at agolubeff.mymusicplayer.SongList$2.onReceive(SongList.java:99)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:866)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Does anybody have an idea how to deal with it?

Comment: put your crash log here. Use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`. `ListView` is outdated

Comment: I second anatoli's request for a log.  I'd also mention that if the view is not currently visible, there is no need to update it.  You always should be able to populate the button, etc. when getVIew is called to make the list item active.

Comment: @Agolubeff have you ever **next** item in `ListView`? It seems, that you not check size of `ListView` by click on `next`

Comment: @Agolubeff  you can scroll to the position using `scrollTo` OR `catch` that `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You should have your status data in an arraylist and make all changes there, then just call notify data set changed on the listview to update what ever is visible.

Comment: @DaleWilson The problem is that i can't set the appropriate image to the button directly in getView function, because it depends on the state of the audiofile. If it is playing I have to set pause image, if it is not - play image. The adapter can't get access to this information about audios.

Comment: @anatoli Yes, I have another item under the lowest one on the screenshot, but it is outside of the ListView.

Comment: then as is said above, you must just update your data in `ArrayList` and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @Juan Can you write an example code illustrating your comment?

Comment: If you can't get the information directly in the `getView` method, then cache it in something that you _can_ access from `getView`  As it is you are trying to update a view that may or may not actually exist -- hence the null pointer exception.